# What is the correct spelling: CSW or CS-W?

Tags: ogc, csw

In different publications I read sometimes CSW or sometimes CS-W for the standard of transferring metadata-documents. What is the correct 'official' spelling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's CSW. Look [here](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/cat) for more information about it than is healthy for one person to read.

Funnily enough in the spec, the abbreviations section has:

> CSW Catalogue Service-Web

So I can see where the hyphenated version comes from, but I've not noticed it in any official documentation.